# Events in hierarchical tree of User Controls

Tags: c#, user-controls, tree

Good day. Program in C#, I need hierarchical tree of UserControls. I used following:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl //my own control
{
    this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(SomeMethodForProcessing);
}

public class TreeNode<T> //universal tree data structure
{
    List<TreeNode<T>> childs;
    T data;
}

TreeNode<MyControl> tree; //using my tree
```

But I need to process my tree depends on user interaction with my controls, for example, user click the control and TreeNode with this control is deleted. Please tell me, how can I do it? May be I must use another approach like this:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl //my control and at the same time tree
{
    List<MyControl> childs;
}

MyControl root; //using my tree
```

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tree node have own events that has handled by tree control. for example when your mouse goes on any node then MouseHover event will be executed in that tree node not directly in Tree control. So, you have to create an event in treenode then you can handle tree control event from here. for example

```
private TreeNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    If (MyControl.ItemClicked != null)    
        MyControl.ItemClicked(this, e);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

this code will be written in your form. the event will be added in your form. But you must have declared event in MyControl user control.

```
private MyControl_ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
        this.Nodes.Remove((TreeNode)sender);

}
```

Comment: And how delete TreeNode which contains the clicked control?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this could be an approach:

```
public class YourNode : TreeNode
{
    public Control Control { get; set; }
}
```

Another way is to use the Tag-Property of the TreeNode-Class. But I'd prefer the first approach.

Comment: But in "TreeNode" already exist "MyControl" field, it is "data". Why do we need for "Control" property?

Comment: OK, in my example above I'm thinking of the standard WinForms [TreeNode-Class] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.treenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
So, you can make a class deriving from TreeNode and add these instances to a TreeView.

Comment: So, I can use WindowsForms.TreeNode class instead TreeNode<T> metaclass. Which is better, define MyControl in the deriving class or in the Tag property of WindowsForms.TreeNode?

Comment: I think you will not need this MyControl class. If you have a from TreeNode derived class like the YourNode class, you can add these instances to a standard TreeView. If you Select or Click a node, you'll get your special YourNode class and you'll have access to the Control-property.